# Python: Call a shell script which calls a bin. With arguments

Tags: shell, python-3.x, arguments

**The context**: There is a map somewhere on the system with bin files which I'd like to call. They are not callable directly though, but through shell scripts which do all kinds of magic and then call the corresponding bin with: `"$ENV_VAR/path/to/the/bin" "$@"` (the software is non-free, that's probably why this construction is used)

**The problem**: Calling this from within Python. I tried to use:

`from subprocess import call
call(["nameOfBin", "-input somefile"])`

But this gave the error `ERROR: nameOfBin - Illegal option: input somefile`. This means the '-' sign in front of 'input' has disapeared along the way (putting more '-' signs in front doesn't help).

**Possible solutions**:

1: In some way preserving the '-' sign so the bin at the end actually takes '-input' as an option instead of 'input'.

2: Fix the magic in a dirty way (I will probably manage), and have a way to call a bin at a location defined by a $ENV_VAR (environment variable).

I searched for both methods, but appearantly nobody before me had such a problem (or I didn't see it: Sorry if that's the case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each item in the list should be a single argument. Replace `"-input somefile"` with `"-input", "somefile"`:

```
from subprocess import call

rc = call(["nameOfBin", "-input", "somefile"])
```